# How to fix a JOptionPane that spams messages?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane

so I created this program and it was working perfectly fine before, however after transferring computers, my program is exploding. The JOptionPane is being spammed and completely running ram pate. If you could please run this program and tell me what is wrong, it would be much appreciated. The program is supposed to create a bingo card on a JFrame.

```
package Bingopackage;



import javax.swing*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.AWTEvent;


public class BingoCard extends JComponent {


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
        //Recover Graphics



        int BValues []= new int [5];
        int IValues []= new int [5];
        int NValues []= new int [4];
        int GValues []= new int [5];
        int OValues []= new int [5];
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," We will now guide you in making your very own Bingo Card");
        for (int B = 0; B<BValues.length; B++)
        {
        String BVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 5 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 1-15");
        BValues[B]=Integer.parseInt(BVal);
        if (BValues[B]<1 || BValues[B]>15)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int B1 = BValues [0];
        int B2 = BValues [1];
        int B3 = BValues [2];
        int B4 = BValues [3];
        int B5 = BValues [4];
        if (B1==B2 || B1==B3 || B1== B4 || B1==B5 || B2==B3 || B2== B4|| B2==B5 || B3== B4 || B3== B5 || B4==B5)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        for (int I = 0; I<IValues.length; I++)
        {
        String IVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 5 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 16-30");
        IValues[I]=Integer.parseInt(IVal);
        if (IValues[I]<16 || IValues[I]>30)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int I1 = IValues [0];
        int I2 = IValues [1];
        int I3 = IValues [2];
        int I4 = IValues [3];
        int I5 = IValues [4];
        if (I1==I2 || I1==I3 || I1== I4 || I1==I5 || I2==I3 || I2== I4|| I2==I5 || I3== I4 || I3== I5 || I4==I5)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        for (int N = 0; N<NValues.length; N++)
        {
        String NVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 4 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 31-45");
        NValues[N]=Integer.parseInt(NVal);
        if (NValues[N]<31 || NValues[N]>45)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int N1 = NValues [0];
        int N2 = NValues [1];
        int N3 = NValues [2];
        int N4 = NValues [3];
        if (N1==N2 || N1==N3 || N1== N4 || N2==N3 || N2== N4|| N3== N4)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        for (int G = 0; G<GValues.length; G++)
        {
        String GVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 5 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 46-60");
        GValues[G]=Integer.parseInt(GVal);
        if (GValues[G]<46 || GValues[G]>60)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int G1 = GValues [0];
        int G2 = GValues [1];
        int G3 = GValues [2];
        int G4 = GValues [3];
        int G5 = GValues [4];
        if (G1==G2 || G1==G3 || G1== I4 || G1==G5 || G2==G3 || G2== G4|| G2==G5 || G3== G4 || G3== G5 || G4==G5)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        for (int O = 0; O<OValues.length; O++)
        {
        String OVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter 5 different numbers"+ "\n" + "that are in the range of 61-75");
        OValues[O]=Integer.parseInt(OVal);
        if (OValues[O]<61 || OValues[O]>75)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }
        }
        int O1 = OValues [0];
        int O2 = OValues [1];
        int O3 = OValues [2];
        int O4 = OValues [3];
        int O5 = OValues [4];
        if (O1==O2 || O1==O3 || O1== O4 || O1==O5 || O2==O3 || O2== O4|| O2==O5 || O3== O4 || O3== O5 || O4==O5)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have failed to comply");
        System.exit (0);
        }


        Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Font bingoFont = new Font ("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN,69);
        g3.setFont(bingoFont);

        Rectangle bingosign = new Rectangle (75,10, 500, 75);
        g3.draw(bingosign);
        g3.drawString ("B   I   N  G  O", 110, 70);

        Rectangle B1Box = new Rectangle (75, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B1Box);

        Rectangle B2Box = new Rectangle (75, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B2Box);

        Rectangle B3Box = new Rectangle (75, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B3Box);

        Rectangle B4Box = new Rectangle (75, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B4Box);

        Rectangle B5Box = new Rectangle (75, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(B5Box);

        Rectangle I1Box = new Rectangle (175, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I1Box);

        Rectangle I2Box = new Rectangle (175, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I2Box);

        Rectangle I3Box = new Rectangle (175, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I3Box);

        Rectangle I4Box = new Rectangle (175, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I4Box);

        Rectangle I5Box = new Rectangle (175, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(I5Box);

        Rectangle N1Box = new Rectangle (275, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N1Box);

        Rectangle N2Box = new Rectangle (275, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N2Box);

        Rectangle N3Box = new Rectangle (275, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N3Box);

        Rectangle N4Box = new Rectangle (275, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N4Box);

        Rectangle N5Box = new Rectangle (275, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(N5Box);

        Rectangle G1Box = new Rectangle (375, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G1Box);

        Rectangle G2Box = new Rectangle (375, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G2Box);

        Rectangle G3Box = new Rectangle (375, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G3Box);

        Rectangle G4Box = new Rectangle (375, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G4Box);

        Rectangle G5Box = new Rectangle (375, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(G5Box);

        Rectangle O1Box = new Rectangle (475, 85, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O1Box);

        Rectangle O2Box = new Rectangle (475, 185, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O2Box);

        Rectangle O3Box = new Rectangle (475, 285, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O3Box);

        Rectangle O4Box= new Rectangle (475, 385, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O4Box);

        Rectangle O5Box = new Rectangle (475, 485, 100, 100);
        g3.draw(O5Box);

        g3.setColor(Color.RED);
        g3.fill(N3Box);

        g3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        String B1String = String.valueOf(B1);
        String B2String = String.valueOf(B2);
        String B3String = String.valueOf(B3);
        String B4String = String.valueOf(B4);
        String B5String = String.valueOf(B5);
        String I1String = String.valueOf(I1);
        String I2String = String.valueOf(I2);
        String I3String = String.valueOf(I3);
        String I4String = String.valueOf(I4);
        String I5String = String.valueOf(I5);
        String N1String = String.valueOf(N1);
        String N2String = String.valueOf(N2);
        String N3String = String.valueOf(N3);
        String N4String = String.valueOf(N4);
        String G1String = String.valueOf(G1);
        String G2String = String.valueOf(G2);
        String G3String = String.valueOf(G3);
        String G4String = String.valueOf(G4);
        String G5String = String.valueOf(G5);
        String O1String = String.valueOf(O1);
        String O2String = String.valueOf(O2);
        String O3String = String.valueOf(O3);
        String O4String = String.valueOf(O4);
        String O5String = String.valueOf(O5);

        g3.drawString(B1String, 90, 160);
        g3.drawString(B2String, 90, 260);
        g3.drawString(B3String, 90, 360);
        g3.drawString(B4String, 90, 460);
        g3.drawString(B5String, 90, 560);
        g3.drawString(I1String, 190, 160);
        g3.drawString(I2String, 190, 260);
        g3.drawString(I3String, 190, 360);
        g3.drawString(I4String, 190, 460);
        g3.drawString(I5String, 190, 560);
        g3.drawString(N1String, 290, 160);
        g3.drawString(N2String, 290, 260);
        g3.drawString(N3String, 290, 460);
        g3.drawString(N4String, 290, 560);
        g3.drawString(G1String, 390, 160);
        g3.drawString(G2String, 390, 260);
        g3.drawString(G3String, 390, 360);
        g3.drawString(G4String, 390, 460);
        g3.drawString(G5String, 390, 560);
        g3.drawString(O1String, 490, 160);
        g3.drawString(O2String, 490, 260);
        g3.drawString(O3String, 490, 360);
        g3.drawString(O4String, 490, 460);
        g3.drawString(O5String, 490, 560);


    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    Font freeSpaceFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN,16);
    g2.setFont(freeSpaceFont);
    g2.drawString("Free", 305, 330);
    g2.drawString("Space", 300, 350);


     }
}

package Bingopackage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import Bingopackage.BingoCard;

public class BingoCardJFrame {

        public static void main(String[] args)
         {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub/
        JFrame frame =new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(700,650);
        frame.setTitle("Bingo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   

        BingoCard component = new BingoCard();
        frame.add(component);

        frame.setVisible(true);

         }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking reading [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) so you can understanding how painting is done in Swing.

Next, remove EVERYTHING NOT not directly related to painting your component from its `paintComponent` method

Swing is an event driven environment, this means that something happens and you respond to it. Swing will repaint you component for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control.

Take a look at [How to create a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details